# unable to save an image created by milon barcode in DNS2D format

Tags: laravel

I can't save the qrcode and datamatrix images produced by the milon barcode package in memory, getting this error:
The non-static method Milon\Barcode\DNS2D::getBarcodePNG() cannot be called statically

On images produced in DNS1D I can save it correctly using the base64_decode function, while the problem occurs with saving DNS2D... This is my code:
[insert image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFCNh.png)

```
$pathQr_code = 'documents/qrcode/'. 'azienda-' . $business->id . '_posta-' . $post->id . '.png';
$qr_code = Storage::disk('public')->put($pathQr_code , base64_decode(DNS2D::getBarcodePNG("$post->qr_code", 'QRCODE')));
```

I've tried different ways but I can't figure out what's wrong.... Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your error is saying that `getBarcodePNG` is not a Static Method, so you can't call it statically via `DNS2D::getBarcodePNG`. You can try `(new DNS2D())->getBarcodePNG(...)` instead maybe?

Comment: Thank you very much I tried as suggested and it seems to work correctly!

Comment: Excellent! Please make sure to read up on the `static` keyword in PHP and how to access static and non-static methods class methods. Cheers 

Comment: to save the images you must always encode them in base64 Ex: 
Es: base64_decode((new DNS2D())->getBarcodePNG("$post->qr_code", DATAMATRIX'));

Comment: Sidenote, this is the comments section; if you've got a solution, post it in the answers section below 

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it as suggested by Tim Lewis by declaring a new instance of DNS2D and wrapping everything with base64_decode.

```
 base64_decode((new DNS2D())->getBarcodePNG("$post->qr_code", DATAMATRIX'));
```